# How to update only one items out of many in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug

Below is my jade html file:

```
                        .form-group(ng-repeat="runningText in runningTexts")
                        .col-md-9
                            label.control-label(style="padding-bottom:8px") Running Text {{$index+1}}
                            textarea.form-control(rows="4" ng-model="runningText.image")
```

Below is my js file:

```
    //This part if for loading the data using ng-repeat. It contain 5 array.
    loadData = function(){
    $http.get(apiPath)
        .success(function(data){  
            if (data != null){       
                $scope.runningTexts = data.displaySetting.runningText;
            }
        })
        .error(function(data) { 
            console.log('wrong');
        });   
     }

     // This is where i want update the data, but I want update the first array only out of 5 array.
       $scope.update = function(data) {
          $scope.runningText[0].image = data.path.image;  // error occurs here.
};
```

Like my question, I only want to update the first array out of the 5 arrays there.

How bout if I have runningText.image and runningText.message. I only want to update the runningText.image in array 1 out of 5 arrays. How to do it?
The error mentioned that $scope.runningText[0].image is undefined. How do we do it?

Comment: $scope.runningTexts[0] check the variable name

Comment: How bout if I have runningText.image and runningText.message. I only want to update the runningText.image in array 1 out of 5 arrays. How to do it?

Comment: When and where are you planing on calling that `update` function?

Comment: I think it does not matter where I call the update function. It can be a mouse click or some other things that triggers.

Comment: It does matter. I mean if you are calling it from a row inside the ng-repeat, is it from the outside, what is data...? Give a better explanation of the problem you're having.

Comment: Is it text or texts ?